# Showing DateTime value in Kendo's child grid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I'm using Kendo UI to create a master/detail grids and show some *DateTime* values in each grid.

In the master grid I can see the value in the expected format. I'm using the same code I used in the master grid to show the value in the child grid. However in the child grid it doesn't show the value in the expected format.

How can I fix this?

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Here's the view's code:

```
@using TelerikTests.Models
@model TestModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

@(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model.Categories)
    .Name("grid_Master")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
        columns.Bound(c => c.Description)
            .Width(50);
        columns.Bound(c => c.DateCategory)
            .Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")   // IT WORKS!!
            .Width(100);
    })
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height: 380px;" })
    .Scrollable(x => x.Height(300))
    .Sortable(x => x.SortMode(GridSortMode.MultipleColumn))
    .Filterable()
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .ServerOperation(false)
        .Batch(true)
        .Model(model =>
        {
            model.Id(p => p.ID);
        })
    )
    .ClientDetailTemplateId("child")
    .Events(e => e.DetailInit("detailGridInit"))
)

<script id="child" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
    @(Html.Kendo().Grid<ProductModel>()
        .Name("gridDetail_#=ID#")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(c => c.ID).Hidden();
            columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct)
                .Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")   // IT DOESN'T WORK
                .Width(70);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Name)
                .Width(70);
            columns.Bound(c => c.Price)
                .Width(70);
        })
        .ToClientTemplate()
    )
</script>

<script>
    function detailGridInit(e) {
        var grid = $("#gridDetail_" + e.data.ID).data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.data(e.data.Products);
    }
</script>
```

Here's the model's code:

```
public class TestModel
{
    public IEnumerable<CategoryModel> Categories { get; set; }
}

public class CategoryModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateCategory { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<ProductModel> Products { get; set; }
}

public class ProductModel
{
    public Guid ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateProduct { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You may take a look at this : http://www.telerik.com/forums/datetime-format-on-grid-cells-date(-)-

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus please check my comment in the answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37327113/showing-datetime-value-in-kendos-child-grid?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution with your help guys. Here it is

**Solution 1**

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct)
   .ClientTemplate("\\#= kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DateProduct), 'yyyy/MM/dd') \\#");
```

---

**Solution 2**

If the *DateTime* data type is *nullable* then we can use a condition in the template to avoid showing *null* in the cell

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct).ClientTemplate(
   "\\# if (DateProduct) { \\#" +
   "\\#=   kendo.toString(kendo.parseDate(DateProduct), 'yyyy/MM/dd') \\#" +
   "\\# } \\#");
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Telerik forum](http://www.telerik.com/forums/datetime-format-on-grid-cells-date(-)-) :

There's a Kendo function you can use to format column fields in a ClientTemplate. So, change:

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct)
       .Format("{0:yyyy/MM/dd}")
       .Width(70);
```

To

```
columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct)
       .ClientTemplate("#= kendo.toString(DateProduct, 'yyyy/MM/dd') #");
```

**Edit**: You have to escape `#` symbol.

```
 columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct)
        .ClientTemplate("\\#= kendo.toString(DateProduct, 'yyyy/MM/dd') \\#");
```

Comment: When I use your solution I get this error "Invalid template". I tried simplifying your template with this statement **columns.Bound(c => c.DateProduct).ClientTemplate("#= DateProduct #");**  and I get this error "Uncaught ReferenceError: DateProduct is not defined"